# Google Core Reporting API v4: get results on hourly basis?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-reporting-api

When using the Google Core Reporting API v4 you can query [day-by-day](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate) by using the API. Now I would like to query on hourly basis instead of daily basis to go one level "deeper" in case sampling occurs.

Now I know this could be done by adding the dimension DateTime but, this leaves me with one dimension slot that I can't use anymore. This is a problem since this is limited to 7. Also if I think about it, adding the ga:hour dimensions might give me more results since it's creating the same report with more detail in it. It does not get the data "for one hour".

I know it is possible to get hourly data when using the Google UI.The question is clear: how do I get hourly data from the Google Core Reporting API v4 (yyyy-MM-dd-HH)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You can only query a whole day of data, and then you can nuse a filter to only see one slice of data, but as you said that will use a dimension on your query and will not improve sampling at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this confirmed my thought.:)

Answer (score 0):

The R package [googleAnalyticsR](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/v4.html#hourly-anti-sampling-calls) has the functionality for hourly anti-sampling.

So it must be possible. I assume that it uses filters to select specific hours of a day, since the package does not support using Google Analytics filters when hourly anti-sampling is required.

So to get your results for a specific hour, you can try including a filter using [`ga:dateHour`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_datehour)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Intresting thought. :) I think that adding the dimension dateHour will increase the report size and thus will not help in anti-sampling like @Eduardo stated.

Comment: Just to clarify. I am not saying to add in another dimension in your query, I am saying to use filters to refine your query, in the API request itself.

Comment: Using a filter only limits the data you'll receive back from Google. Sampling is based on 1. the daterange and 2. the amount of sessions in the requested daterange. For example, querying for 2 years of data and filtering it to one hour will still get you sampled results since the daterange and the amount of sessions might be to large. Using a filter will not prevent sampling. :(